# How to use external pod template in Airflow

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I am trying to use my own pod template with KubernetesExecutor. So, in the official documentation of airflow.cfg, there's a reference that we can use external pod template

```
# Path to the YAML pod file. If set, all other kubernetes-related fields are ignored.
pod_template_file =
```

I tried to use it by specifying the path to a pod template file, but it's not working at all.

Do you have any idea how can I use it or how to solve this?
Thank you.